# How to decrypt encrypted emails of lotus notes pro-grammatically?

Tags: encryption, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, c-api, ibm-domino

I am using the C API to fetch the email document property. Currently, I am facing some issues while retrieving the encrypted emails from Lotus Notes. On analyzing the properties of the encrypted email document, I found that the encrypted email data is stored in the `$SealData` property. I did googling in order to decrypt those emails and found some links which describes only the overview of the process. But, I need some documents/ideas, which will describe the clear process to decrypt the email.

These documenta are explaining only the overview of encryption and decryption process.

- http://second-ext.inttrust.ru/Lotus/NotesWeb/Today.nsf/9148b29c86ffdcd385256658007aaa0f/443c6ed28496c1e7852566090060ca17?OpenDocument
- https://www.exportnotes.com/articles/encryption-in-lotus-notes.html
- http://second-ext.inttrust.ru/Lotus/NotesWeb/Today.nsf/DisplayForm/24D3F7B03BCAF0C388256ABB00730519?OpenDocument

Another one document having some programmatic example, but, I'm not sure whether it will work or not. Also, I don't want to remove those `$SealData` property form the existing item:

https://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Remove-Encryption-from-Mail

At this moment, I am just stuck in how to achieve this goal (i.e. decrypting encrypted email). I am quite happy to hear some updates regarding my query.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The 2nd document above describes the process rather well.  I assume you understand that you need the id-file of the owner of a mail database (and their password) in order to be able to decrypt their mail. If you do not have the id, you cannot decrypt mails that were encrypted using the same id. By the way: if you could decrypt mails simply by using some API, encryption would be rather pointless, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. But, I need to do the things which are mentioned in the second document in programmatic way. Hence, I am looking to some references to do the decryption part.

Answer (score 1):

Decryption is done with NSFNoteDecrypt or NSFNoteCipherDecrypt, but your current Notes ID file must have the correct private key. There is no other way to supply keys. It *must* be contained in the ID file.

If your question is really how to re-save the document with encryption removed, then your last link tells you exactly what you need to do -- except of course that you need to do those steps in the C API instead of in the higher-level LotusScript API. I.e., NSFItemDelete calls for "$Seal", "$SealData" and "Encrypt". and then NSFNoteUpdate. But again, if you are not running under an ID file that has the correct private key, none of this will work.

P.S. Your third link is an article I wrote 19 years ago!

Comment: P.S. I forgot to mention this. It probably goes without saying, but since the higher-level API does the decrypt automatically... Be sure to decrypt before you make those NSFItemDelete calls!